Copy Material From Face to Instance in Geomtry Nodes While Distributing Instances
I'm basically working with this cube with 2 different materials applied to it:

You can see some instances of "bumps" distributed on the face. I want the instances to have the same material as the face they are on. Is that achievable in geometry nodes?
I do not want to use an image texture with different colors as a source (possible but not what I want here), as I’m working with multiple separate materials: I want the complete material itself assigned to the instances.
Blend File

The linked answer shows how to get the color of an existing texture/image in Geometry Nodes and pass it to the shader. However, there is no way to get the color assigned by a shader into Geometry Nodes and process it there (and then pass it back to the shader). Remember: in Blender, the geometry is always created first, and the shader works at the end of the chain. The only option is to define the colors of the faces as well as the colors of the instances in Geometry Nodes, and then have the shader process these values.

@quellenform He said materials, not colors. This is not a duplicate of the linked question. I would remove my upvote of your comment, but my browser is malfunctioning.

If you are dealing with multiple materials with variable numbers, then there is a solution. However, the instances have to be realized. If, on the other hand, you absolutely need instances with different materials, then unfortunately this can only be solved depending on the number of materials used, since the Set Material Index node cannot be used on instances. Hence the question: instances or realized geometry?
